What reverb is used on the Fugees 'Killing me Softly'?
What reverb is used on the Fugees 'Killing me Softly'? I have a theory that it is total analog bliss.

and apologies in advance if i imagined any reverb!

I'm guessing it's tape manipulation (static, imperfections, dirty mixes) with a slight digital delay (if so). Sounds fun.

This questions has been floating around for a bit so figured I'd try an answer... I'll discuss it broadly first and then try and zone in given details of the actual situation they recorded in.
I assume you mean the vocal reverb on the choral vocals, the rest of the track is very dry.
I'm not sure what Total Analog Bliss is, theres the Chase Bliss CXM or similar but this was not around in 1996 when this song was released. Reverb options in 1996 were more limited than today, you wouldn't get the same level of quality from a small pedal unit. Reverbs in '96 were either real rooms, analog plates (large sheets of metal, several meters across sometimes), real springs (like in guitar amps or sometimes standalone) and newer, VERY expensive digital arrivals such as the lexicon-PCM series.
Software based reverbs at the time were very basic and grainy, and were not used in high budget recordings.
Similarly I don't think they used digital delay here, it just doesn't sound like it. This recording is before pro tools was widely adopted (which was around 2000) and when DAW use was limited more to producers of electronic music, I THINK this would have been recorded to tape so we can rule out delay plugins (that said, given the way they set up for recording MAY have meant they went with an early DAW rather than tape, but I can't find any info on it, I suspect tape). Bucket brigade analog delays existed, as did ACTUAL tape delay (using a tape machine, the technique that 'delay' as an effect is named after), and so did early rack mounted / pedal digital delays. But I don't detect any of these on this recording really.
The reverb on Killing Me Softly doesn't really sound like a plate, and real room reverbs (that is, chambers in recording studios where tracks were literally played back in and recorded to apply reverb) are usually smaller than this reverb sounds. That said, in the US (I am UK) they have a few studios with really huge real chambers for this technique (eg Blackbird in Nashville has one, I don't know if they did in 1996, but critically, the Fugees didn't record there).
Reportedly the Fugees took a $135,000 advance from Ruffhouse Records and set up a studio to record this themselves. So it's a 'home recording', ruling out big chambers to play with. They could have easily afforded a plate with this budget, but as I say it doesn't sound like that.
They COULD have taken a choir to a church 'on-location' and recorded it beautifully, but this was much harder in the 90's, and it sounds to me like the chorus is all Lauren singing the parts, multi tracked. This would point towards it being a high end early digital reverb in their high-budget home studio. Something like the Lexicon PCM 70, those are expensive but their budget would have easily afforded one! I think thats about as close as you'd be able to guess. I've used the early Lexicon PCM's and they could get this sound no probs, and I'd put my money on it's something like that!
